# R: Efficiently calculate multiplication'sum

Tags: r

If I have a matrix A (5000-by-6000), which means it has n rows and m columns, `a_ij` is the element. I would like to calculate `sum (k=1..m, l=1..m) (a[i,l]*a[j,k])` (i.e., [this formula](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5nw7ha5j8pkgcr9/sum.pdf?dl=0)), which is 5000-by-5000. What is an efficient way to calculate such a formula?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this the trace of $AA^T$? How about `matrixcalc::matrix.trace(A %*% t(A))`?

Comment: This is getting close votes for lack f claity. Why not use an example that is 100 times smaller.

Comment: Thanks Ben for helping edit my question.

Comment: @Hugh, flodel gave the right answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your expression so the double sum of products becomes the product of the two rowsums `i` and `j`. So your output matrix is essentially the kronecker product of the rowsums:

```
x <- rowSums(a)
x %o% x
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It works very well. It seems understanding the means of formula is so important.